# Alternate for googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener since deprecated

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Since googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener is deprecated what is the best way for checking the my current location continuously?

I couldn't find any answer.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setOnMyLocationChangeListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener)

Answer (score 3):

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#public-methods) it is said:

> use com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead.
>   FusedLocationProviderApi provides improved location finding and power
>   usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot. See the
>   MyLocationDemoActivity in the sample applications folder for example
>   example code, or the [Location Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location).